# Problems in configuring Homestead.yaml in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and I am going to set up the VM for my apps. I am following docs well and I am almost done with configuration. I am stuck here.

I have Windows 8 and my Homestead.yaml file looks like this:

```
authorize: E:/laravel_projects/Homestead/keys.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: E:/laravel_projects
      to: E:/vagrant/laravel_projects

sites:
    - map: learn.app
      to: E:/vagrant/laravel_projects/myfirstapp/public

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

Error is something like this when I run Vagrant up in cmd.

```
E:/laravel_projects/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:26:in `read': No such file or directory - E:/laravel_projects/Homestead/keys.pub (Errno::ENOENT)
    from E:/laravel_projects/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:26:in `block in configure'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm_provisioner.rb:72:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm_provisioner.rb:72:in `add_config'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm.rb:285:in `provision'
    from E:/laravel_projects/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:24:in `configure'
    from E:/laravel_projects/Homestead/Vagrantfile:9:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:103:in `block (2 levels) in load'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:97:in `each'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:97:in `block in load'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:94:in `each'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:94:in `load'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:614:in `new'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:614:in `vagrantfile'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:399:in `host'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:198:in `block in action_runner'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:386:in `hook'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:596:in `unload'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/bin/vagrant:177:in `ensure in <main>'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/bin/vagrant:177:in `<main>'
```

My project path is E:/laravel_projects.

Comment: Console errors are best supplied as text, not screenshots - it is easier for people to read. Would you swap that?

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like this:

```
folders:
    - map: E:/laravel_projects
      to: /home/vagrant/laravel_projects
  - map: E:/laravel_projects/myfirstapp
      to: /home/vagrant/laravel_projects/myfirstapp

sites:
    - map: learn.app
      to: /home/vagrant/laravel_projects/myfirstapp/public
```

Your linux VM will not have an E drive.

Comment: Thanks gravy.. but not helping much. Still getting a bunch of errors. Don't know what I am missing. Is there anything to change in key section??

Comment: Also, see updated answer. You need to include `myfirstapp` in your folders. Finally, your `keys.pub` file is not in `E:/laravel_projects/Homestead/keys.pub` as per the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the first line in your error:

> E:/laravel_projects/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:26:in `read': No such file or directory - E:/laravel_projects/Homestead/keys.pub (Errno::ENOENT)

Apparently the key is not there. Make sure you have generated a SSH-key and specified a correct path to it.

Also, in your Homestead.yaml:

```
keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

This is the path to your private key, though it is a *nix path. You need to set this to the path to your generated private key on your Windows system.